# Starting AppFabric Cache Cluster automatically

Tags: appfabric

Is there a way to start the cache cluster automatically on system startup? I'm running it on a remote PC and when it gets restarted I have to remote into it and restart the cache cluster from Powershell using Start-CacheCluster, and would like to not have to do this.

Thanks,

James

Comment: Why not install the AppFabric administration bits locally and configure it to be in the same cluster as your remote PC? Then you should be able to start the cluster from your local PC with Start-CacheCluster.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes - if you change the startup mode of the AppFabric Caching Service from Manual to Automatic, then the service will start once the server has finished booting.
[image: AppFabric Service configuration window]
<sub>(source: [philippursglove.com](http://philippursglove.com/stackoverflow/appfabricserviceconfig.png))</sub>

I suspect that as AppFabric starts to move into production clusters, this will become a 'best practice' thing to do in order to get maximum uptime on the cluster.

Comment: Hmmm. I don't seem to have that service available, is it registered on installation? I think perhaps I have an older version than you, I'm running Beta1 I believe (AseSetup_amd64_6.1.exe)

Comment: Ah, in Beta 1 it's called something like (IIRC) "Microsoft Project codenamed 'Velocity'", it'll appear about halfway down your services list. I recommend moving up to Beta 2 or the RC though, I've found it more reliable than Beta 1.

Comment: I found that even though I'd set it to Automatic, sometimes the service wasn't started up automatically. I looked into it today, and noticed a Windows update completed message. Looking in the event log, I saw errors from the service, related to the DB config store - I suspect the DB either went offline while the AppFabric service was running or starting up. Hope this info helps someone else.

Comment: BEWARE using this approach with XML based configuration. This is the quote from James Broome article mentioned below: "...Changing the AppFabric Caching Service to have a startup type of Automatic in the Services control panel resulted in some really unpredictable behaviour. We are using an XML based configuration store, so maybe this was never going to work, but all sorts of errors and crashes started appearing in the Event Log, basically the cache became unusable until this was changed back to Manual."

Answer (score 6):

James Broome wrote a great post on this: http://jamesbroo.me/automatically-starting-the-windows-server-appfabric-caching-service/