# start cachecluster automatically when server starts up

Tags: caching, powershell, appfabric

I have installed AppFabric on my machine. Everytime I restart my machine I have restart the AppFabric caching by running "start-cachecluster" in the powershell "Caching Administration Windows PowerShell". How can I set this up to run everytime the machine is restarted?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Starting AppFabric Cache Cluster automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874786/starting-appfabric-cache-cluster-automatically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the startup type of the AppFabricCachingService from Manual to Automatic - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874786/starting-appfabric-cache-cluster-automatically/2877170#2877170).

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely need to use a startup task, or your run-this-on-startup method of your choice, to invoke the command when the machine boots.

If you are using a network-share bound cluster config, you cannot auto-start the cluster as the hosts perform the lead host operations in-memory, which requires a particular startup order for Cluster, config, hosts, etc.

SQL Server configs should be able to support an auto-start scenario (just startmode=auto on the service) on the service, as the lead operations are offloads to the database config.

It's a desperately needed feature which makes AppFabric and HA nearly impossible.